# Convert Date format from Oracle DB to SFDC

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Need your assistance to convert the date format from ORACLE-DB to SFDC in Mule 4 - Dataweave 2.0.

Here is the date format receiving from Oracel-DB `16-DEC-19 02.24.19.385439000 PM` or `16-DEC-19 02.24.19.385439000 AM`. This need to be convert into SFDC format `2019-12-16`.

Awaiting for your response. Thanks Much...!!!

Answer (score 1):

This code parses the string representation of the date and then creates a new string representation with the desired format.

```
"16-DEC-19 02.24.19.385439000 PM" 
  as LocalDateTime {format: "dd-MMM-yy' 'hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS' 'a"} 
  as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

Besides this, check if you are not getting Java dates from the DB or if the SFDC connector is not expecting a Java date instead.

For other formats, you can check the Java Date formatting patterns https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for your help and it worked as expected.... 

need one more transformation 

Input : `{
"date":"Dec 30 2020  6:21AM"
} `

Ouput: `30-DEC-20 04.01.21.000000000 AM`